# Unable to add data into database with foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql

In reference to my earlier question at

[Unable to add foreign keys to mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111341/unable-to-add-foreign-keys-to-mysql-database)

I wanted to know, what is the best way to insert new data into the section, takes and teaches tables since the foreign key constraints are already present? I don't want to drop the table and rebuild the schema as there is too much data that needs to be re-entered.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the value in to table like

```
insert into table_name values("a", "b", "c");
```

This is the common syntax of insert statement. Coming to your tables

While inserting into other tables also make sure that you are not violating the primary and foreign key constraints.

Eg:

```
Student:
ID    name    Dept_name    tot_credit
1     abc     EE            3
2     def     CS            3

Department:

Deptname    building    budget
EE           1            200
CS           2            299
IS           3            900

course:
courseid    title    dept_name    credits
44       Algorithms   CS           3
899       OS          CS           3
```

Now if you are trying to insert into section it should go like this:

```
insert into section values(44, 199, 5, 2000, 500, 50, "Whatever format");
```

Since this is referring only to the course table

Ok try this:

```
insert into teaches values(instructor_id(existing in instructor table), course_id(match section table), secid(from section table), semester(from section table), year(from section table));
```

Good luck.

Comment: yea i know the normal way to insert into a table .... my query is "insert into teaches values (11, 'CIS437', '1', 'Spring', 2012);" .... but i get the error "ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`nseshan`.`teaches`, CONSTRAINT `teaches_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`, `sec_id`, `semester`, `year`) REFERENCES `section` (`course_id`, `sec_id`, `semester`, `year`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON U)" ... any help?

Comment: You should make sure that you are not adding any foreign key values that does not exist. Adding new values would give you this error as you are violating the foreign key constraints.